# how to create a Static month/day, with dynamic year in excel

Tags: excel, date, dynamic

I have a formula that incorporates a static date range from feb 1 to 28th. I need the dates to stay the same but the year to change.

=SUMIFS('2017 Booked Orders'!$H:$H,'2017 Booked Orders'!$C:$C,$B11, '2017 Booked Orders'!$M:$M,'Customer Dashboard'!$B$5, '2017 Booked Orders'!$K:$K,**">=2/1/2017"**,'2017 Booked Orders'!$K:$K,**"<=2/28/2017"**)

i want to reference a dynamic year cell but cant get the code to work in excel. Any help is really apreciated. I just need the year to change once we reach 2018, 2019 ext. Not the month or date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use DATE() and refer to a cell for the year:

```
=SUMIFS('2017 Booked Orders'!$H:$H,'2017 Booked Orders'!$C:$C,$B11, '2017 Booked Orders'!$M:$M,'Customer Dashboard'!$B$5, '2017 Booked Orders'!$K:$K,">=" & DATE(A1,2,1),'2017 Booked Orders'!$K:$K,"<="  & DATE(A1,2,28))
```

Where A1 is the cell in which you put the year you want.

Comment: I tried that earlier, I get the following error. I also tried changing the format of the reference cell including plain text, date, number. but the same error keeps poping up. Any other thoughts? "there's a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula? when the first character is an equal or minus sing, excel thinks is a formula. " the error is not very much help in solving the problem.

Comment: @Coopa I forgot the `&` to concatenate the strings.  See edit